# I am trying to calculate the length of a string, but I am getting NOTICE error

Tags: php, string

**This is my script where I am calculating the length of string without library function, but I am getting error?**

```
<?php 

$name = "Mohammad Umar";

$i = 0;

while ($name[$i] != ''){
   $i++;
}

echo $i;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your string there are 13 offsets, from 0 to 12.

There isn't any offset which equals to `''`, since you only have alpha characters and a space.

So, your `while` loop cannot stop and reaches the undefined 13th offset.

Were you actually trying to reach the space ? If this is the case, try to test `$name[$i]` on `' '`

**EDIT**

To compute the length of the string without `strlen`, but with at least one variable handling function called `isset`, I would do this :

```
$name = "Mohammad Umar";

$i = -1;
while (isset($name[++$i]));

echo $i;
```

Comment: Actually I want to calculate the length of string without library function, so Iooked it over stackoverflow and found the script. So could you tell me what is the actual meaning of $name[$i] != '' "???...in the condition of while. And if you have a better approach, do help me. Also explain about offset. Thanks.

Comment: Well, an offset is an index in your string. It goes from 0 to 12 in your example. Then, I don't really see the point of wanting to compute the length without library functions...Personnaly, I would at least use one called `isset`, see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$name = "Mohammad Umar";
$name_length=strlen($name);
$i = 0;

for($i=0;$i<$name_length;$i++)
{
  if($name[$i] == '')
  {
    echo $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no output for the script